# MUI Custom Text Field loses focus on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, use-state

I'm using [MUI](https://mui.com/) library to create my [React Js](https://reactjs.org/) app.

Here I'm using the [controlled Text Field](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled) component to create a simple search UI.

But there is something strange. **The `Text Field` component loses focus after its value is changed.**
This is my first time facing this problem. I never faced this problem before.

**How this could happen? And what is the solution.**

Here is the code and the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-lost-focus-oenoo?

Note: if I remove the `breakpoint type` from the code, the `Text Field` component still loses focus after its value is changed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's because you're defining a component inside another component, so that component definition is recreated every time the component renders (and your component renders every time the user types into the input).

Two solutions:

1. Don't make it a separate component.

   Instead of:

   ```
   const MyComponent = () => {
     const MyInput = () => <div><input /></div>; // you get the idea

     return (
       <div>
         <MyInput />
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

   Do:

   ```
   const MyComponent = () => {    
     return (
       <div>
         <div><input /></div> {/* you get the idea */}
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
2. Define the component outside its parent component:

   ```
   const MyInput = ({value, onChange}) => (
     <div>
       <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
     </div>
   );

   const MyComponent = () => {
     const [value, setValue] = useState('');

     return (
       <div>
         <MyInput
           value={value}
           onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}
         />
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

Comment: Or use useMemo() to wrap your component and use it somewhere else.

Comment: Can I just say “Thank you so much for this”? It’s a life saver.

Answer (score 9):

Be careful about your components' keys, if you set dynamic value as a key prop, it will also cause focus lost. Here is an example

```
{people.map(person => (
    <div key={person.name}>
      <Input type="text" value={person.name} onChange={// function which manipulates person name} />
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer when u have multiple items...

Answer (score 7):

For MUI V5

Moved your custom-styled code outside the component

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTheme, TextField, styled } from '@mui/material'; 
import { SearchOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';

interface SearchInputProps {   placeholder?: string;   onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;   value: string; dataTest?: string; }

const StyledSearchInput = styled(TextField)(({ theme }: any) => {   return {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      borderRadius: '0.625rem',
      fontSize: '1rem',
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: `${theme.palette.text.secondary}`
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: `${theme.palette.primary}`
      }
    }   }; });

const SearchInput: React.FC<SearchInputProps> = ({   placeholder = 'Search...',   onChange,   value,   dataTest,   ...props }) => {   const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <StyledSearchInput
      {...props}
      onChange={onChange}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      variant="outlined"
      value={value}
      inputProps={{ 'data-testid': dataTest ? dataTest : 'search-input' }}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <SearchOutlined
            sx={{ color: theme.palette.text.secondary, height: '1.5rem', width: '1.5rem' }}
          />
        )
      }}
    />   ); };

export default SearchInput;
```

Comment: it was a life saving answer

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the conversation. But adding to [SchemeSonic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74753010/19465550), if you have 'dynamic' component keys which you're passing to a component which renders, for arguments sake, a list of input fields, and you want to focus on a specific input field when it is mounted, you can use a ref to store a mapping of the input field ids to onMount callbacks.

Then, after mounting you can set a timeout to call the onMount callbacks.
This way, you can focus on the component (or do anything using the input ref) when it is mounted.

Here's a snippet to the [codesandbox solution.](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-browser-wyhlst?file=/Demo.tsx)

```
<InputFieldList
      inputFieldIds={inputFieldIds}
      renderInputField={(id) => (
        <StyledTextField
          key={id}
          label={id}
          variant="outlined"
          size="small"
          inputRef={id === fieldToFocus ? fieldToFocusRef : undefined}
          value={values[id]}
          onChange={handleChange(id)}
        />
      )}
      onMount={(id) => {
        // Focus on the input field when it is mounted
        if (id === fieldToFocus) fieldToFocusRef.current?.focus();
      }}
    />
```