# Problems with renderHeader prop MUI Data Grid Pro component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I'm using [Material UI DataGridPro](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/#commercial-version) component to build a React Js app.

I want to create a custom filtering and column showing/hiding views.

The red box in the image below is an `IconButton` for the filtering view and the blue box is for the column showing/hiding view.

[image]

The column showing/hiding feature works fine but the filtering feature doesn't.

If the filter icon is clicked, then the `DataGridPro` header will show some `Select` and `TextField` components as the filter fields like this image below.

[image]

If we change the value one of the `Select` and `TextField` components, the value will not be shown in the selected component itself.
But if we print the value of the `Select` and `TextField` components on the console, the value will be printed (but only for one character for the `TextField` component).

There are 2 errors from this case:

1. the value of the `Select` and `TextField` components will not be shown in the component themselves
2. if we select one of the `MenuItem` components and select outside the `Select` component, there will be an error

```
Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Here is the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-mui-data-grid-render-header-xmwf0?file=/src/App.jsx

**How could these (the errors) happen and what is the solution?**

**Note:**

The problem might come from the controlled components (the `Select` and `Text Field` components that have value and on change props) inside the header of the `Data Grid` component.

If my statement above is true, this `renderHeader` case might be similar to this case [MUI Custom Text Field loses focus on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164306/mui-custom-text-field-loses-focus-on-state-change) but I still haven't found the answer for this `DataGridPro` issue yet.