# Is it possible to have simple filter in the colmns header when using Mui datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Mui data-grid in my react app.
The PM consist's that he wants to filter the data like this:

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9agUI.jpg)

I don't know if it's possible or not and how to implement that.

I did something by renderHeader prop like: [Problems with renderHeader prop MUI Data Grid Pro component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739203/problems-with-renderheader-prop-mui-data-grid-pro-component).

and the code is https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-mui-data-grid-render-header-xmwf0?file=/src/App.jsx

```
  const filterOnColumns = [
    {
      field: 'name',
      headerName: 'Name',
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 200,
      renderHeader: () => (
        <TextField
          variant="standard"
          label="Name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          // value={filters.name}
          // onChange={handleFiltersChange}
          onKeyDown={event => event.stopPropagation()}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'phone',
      headerName: 'Phone',
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 200,
      renderHeader: () => (
        <TextField
          variant="standard"
          label="Phone"
          type="text"
          name="phone"
          // value={filters.phone}
          // onChange={handleFiltersChange}
          onKeyDown={event => event.stopPropagation()}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'email',
      headerName: 'Email',
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 200,
      renderHeader: () => (
        <FilterInput
          variant="standard"
          label="Email"
          type="text"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleFiltersChange}
          value={filters.email}
          updateFilters={setFilters}
        />
      ),
    },
```

But when I click on the header's input, the sorting is also working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to call `stopPropagation` on `onClick` too:

```
onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
```

Next to uncontrol the TextField you can only pass `defaultValue` to it.

Remains only to filter the rows variable with the updated filters.

Updated code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-mui-data-grid-render-header-forked-50yv4d?file=/src/App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Here is improved code for dynamic header rendering for n number of columns.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-mui-data-grid-render-header-forked-6bp70h?file=/src/App.jsx

hope it will help many others.

```
  const handleFiltersChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setFilters({
        ...filters,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      });
      let key = event.target.name;
      if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
        const filteredRows = rowss.filter((character) => {
          console.log("character ", character, character[key]);
          return character[key]
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
        });
        setRowss(filteredRows);
      } else {
        setRowss(rows);
      }
    },
    [filters]
  );

  const filterOnColumns = useMemo(() =>
    initialColumns.map((item, index) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        renderHeader: (params) => {
          return (
            <TextField
              variant="standard"
              className={classes.columnFilter}
              label={item.headerName}
              type="text"
              name={item.field}
              defaultValue={filters.name}
              onChange={handleFiltersChange}
              onKeyDown={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
              onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            />
          );
        }
      };
    })
  );
```